# Angularfire Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following the example Getting started with Firebase and Angular - Firecasts #4 and I keep getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined.
```

Any ideas?

Here is my app.js:

```js
    angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])
    .constant('FirebaseUrl', 'https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com/')
    .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
    .service('users', Users)
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyController)
    .config(ApplicationConfig);

function ApplicationConfig($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'MyCtrl as ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/myctrl.html'
    });
}

function Users(rootRef, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    var usersRef = rootRef.child('users');
    this.get = function get(id) {
        return $firebaseObject(usersRef.child(id));
    };

    this.all = function all() {
        return $firebaseArray(usersRef);
    };
}

function MyController(users) {
    this.users = users.all();
}
```

This is my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="app">
     <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularFire</title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there error being thrown here: `.service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])`?

Comment: Hi @theblindprophet. That is where the error is coming from.

Comment: You are missing `var rootRef =  new Firebase('https://<my-app>.firebase.io.com'). The Firecasts puts some importance on that.

Comment: Thank you @theblindprophet. Where should I define the rootRef?

Comment: Look back at the Firecast. Its inside of `MyController`

Comment: Thank you so much @theblindprophet. Could you perhaps post this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: It worked? Just making sure

Comment: It is working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert:

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://<my-app>.firebase.io.com');
```

inside of `MyController` as seen in this [image: picture].

The commentator explains that `Firebase` is injected into to the controller as a "Firebase constructor function."

`'FirebaseUrl'` is the url defined above inside `.constant`.

His explaination is quite fast, but either way you need that line of code to help define the reference.

Please edit or comment on this post if anyone has more insight.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using new version of firebase. Go ahead and rewrite this example like it is said here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#monitor_authentication_state_numbered.

You need point 4: "In the new SDKs, you no longer instantiate a database references via new Firebase. Instead, you will initialize the SDK via firebase.initializeApp()..."

Answer (score 0):

I add this as answer to use the link: [new docs](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md)

As Boas Babs said, the new version uses a different approach to get the database reference.

```
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();

  // download the data into a local object
  $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
});
```